# Draw rectangle with mouse and fill with color on mouseup

Tags: html, konvajs

I am using Konva library for drawing a canvas and dragging images onto it

My question is how can I select a part of canvas and fill color to the selected portion using Konva

1) users select a portion by dragging mouse
2) fill color what he wants to the selected portion

Comment: If you could review my answer and confirm if helped please ?

Comment: it helped a lot, thank you Vanquished Wombat

Comment: Hi - if my answer was correct please could you mark it as the correct answer by clicking the tick. Marking the correct or most helpful answer helps other people judge its relevance and awards points to the answerer. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The only way to have part of the canvas filled is to use a shape.

This snippet should get you going.

To select the fill color you will need to open some kind of custom color selection process in the mouseup event.

```js
// Set up the canvas and shapes
var s1 = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 300, height: 200});
var layer1 = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
s1.add(layer1);

// draw a background rect to catch events.
var r1 = new Konva.Rect({x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200, fill: 'gold' })    
layer1.add(r1)

// draw a rectangle to be used as the rubber area
var r2 = new Konva.Rect({x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, stroke: 'red', dash: [2,2]})    
r2.listening(false); // stop r2 catching our mouse events.
layer1.add(r2)

s1.draw() // First draw of canvas.
var posStart;
var posNow;
var mode = '';
function startDrag(posIn){
  posStart = {x: posIn.x, y: posIn.y};
  posNow = {x: posIn.x, y: posIn.y};
}

function updateDrag(posIn){ 
  
  // update rubber rect position
  posNow = {x: posIn.x, y: posIn.y};
  var posRect = reverse(posStart,posNow);
  r2.x(posRect.x1);
  r2.y(posRect.y1);
  r2.width(posRect.x2 - posRect.x1);
  r2.height(posRect.y2 - posRect.y1);
  r2.visible(true);  
   
  s1.draw(); // redraw any changes.
  
}

// start the rubber drawing on mouse down.
r1.on('mousedown', function(e){ 
  mode = 'drawing';
  startDrag({x: e.evt.layerX, y: e.evt.layerY})
  })

// update the rubber rect on mouse move - note use of 'mode' var to avoid drawing after mouse released.
r1.on('mousemove', function(e){ 
    if (mode === 'drawing'){
      updateDrag({x: e.evt.layerX, y: e.evt.layerY})
    }
})

// here we create the new rect using the location and dimensions of the drawing rect.
r1.on('mouseup', function(e){ 
    mode = '';
    r2.visible(false);
    var newRect = new Konva.Rect({
      x: r2.x(),
      y: r2.y(),
      width: r2.width(),
      height: r2.height(),
      fill: 'red',
      listening: false
    })
    layer1.add(newRect);
    s1.draw();
})


// reverse co-ords if user drags left / up
function reverse(r1, r2){
  var r1x = r1.x, r1y = r1.y, r2x = r2.x,  r2y = r2.y, d;
  if (r1x > r2x ){
    d = Math.abs(r1x - r2x);
    r1x = r2x; r2x = r1x + d;
  }
  if (r1y > r2y ){
    d = Math.abs(r1y - r2y);
    r1y = r2y; r2y = r1y + d;
  }
    return ({x1: r1x, y1: r1y, x2: r2x, y2: r2y}); // return the corrected rect.     
}
```

```css
p
{
  padding: 4px;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>Click & drag on the background to draw a rectangle and fill it.
</p>
<div id='container1' style="display: inline-block; width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"></div>
```